# Django : Passing multiple args in HttpResponseRedirect reverse function

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I'm trying to pass multiple args in django's HttpResponseRedirect reverse function, but I keep getting this error

*Reverse for 'DemoVar.views.success' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'company': u'Company ', 'sid': 47606734}' not found.*

```
 #Calling function
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DemoVar.views.success',kwargs={'sid':int(ph), 'company':company}))

 #Function definition
 def success(request, sid, company):

 #urls.py
 url(r'^success/(?P<sid>[\d]+)/(?P<company>[\w\d-]+)/$','success', name='DemoVar_success'),
```

I tried passing 'args' in reverse function, but with similar error. Please help.

Update: Tried passing the args as a tuple. The output remains same.

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DemoVar.views.success',args=(ph, company,)))

 #Error 
 Reverse for 'DemoVar.views.success' with arguments '(47606734, 'Dummy Company')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: Your regex won't match against "Dummy Company", because it has a space.

Comment: @Daniel : Absolutely, passing arguments without space works perfectly. Thanks. I changed my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regex inside urls.py for corresponding function url was wrong. Apparently Django looks at urls.py to figure out the type of inputs for the view function, which in my case was 'DemoVar.views.success'. Since the url's regex didn't allow for 'spaces', django gave an error. I changed to regex to accommodate an input containing spaces.

```
 url(r'^success/(?P<sid>[\d]+)/(?P<company>[\s\w\d-]+)/$','success', name='DemoVar_success'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is named `DemoVar_success` not `DemoVar.views.success`.

Comment: One can pass path to the view directly as well.